# Using multiple ranges to create a vector in R

Tags: r, range, vectorization

How can I create a vector in R using vector ranges. For example say I have two vectors that designate range limits. Say,

```
V1=c(1,10,20)

V2=c(3,12,21)
```

I would like to do something that would intuitively look like:

```
c(V1:V2)

[1] 1 2 3 10 11 12 20 21
```

{this is meant to be the vectorized equivalent of c(1:3,10:12,20:21)}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Map` function.

```
unlist(Map(`:`, V1, V2))
[1]  1  2  3 10 11 12 20 21
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative with the *data.table* package.  If we create a grouping variable we can run `:` by each group then grab the column at the end.

```
library(data.table)
data.table(id = seq_along(V1), V1, V2)[, V1:V2, by = id]$V1
# [1]  1  2  3 10 11 12 20 21
```

Comment: That is almost 2+ times faster compared to `Map`. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me anymore - `V1=c(1,10,20);V2=c(3,12,21);data.table::data.table(id = seq_along(V1), V1, V2)[, V1:V2, by = id]$V1
# [1]  1 10 20`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1, V2)
dt <- dt[rep(1:.N, V2-V1+1), i := .I, by = V1][,
         res := 0:(.N-1) + V1, by = i]
```